# Devise custom sign up parameters not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

### Preamble

As a little bit of a setup to the problem, we have an authenticatable user model that is separate from the user model that contains non-authentication related data.

### Problem

As the title suggests, adding custom fields to the built in `configure_sign_up_params` method does not actually permit the fields in the `create` action. I've generated the relevant controller and views with `rails generate devise:controllers user` and `rails generate devise:views user`, and made modifications to both. In the view:

```
<h2>Custom User Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= fields_for(:extra_user_attributes) do |pa| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= pa.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= pa.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= pa.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= pa.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "user/shared/links" %>
```

We have a nested `:extra_user_attributes` field that we need permitted, so in the devise generated controller, I uncommented a couple of lines and added the relevant logic:

```
class CustomUser::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  # POST /resource
  def create
    ap sign_up_params
  end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:extra_user_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name]])
  end
end
```

This is where I got stuck. I've tried several permutations in the `keys` array, but everything I've tried thus far yields the same result. For my own sanity, I verified the `before_action` actually does trigger.

As for the endpoint, I'm simply printing the output to the console just to see what the permitted signup parameters are.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5MqzDUsbrdMdE0Z7/Vw70zJddaKR+0eLYdnum3wEyTShNjB9o3Nb4ZsnE0dZEPlgs4SheZtQad0VpuIGtCeSmw==", "extra_user_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>""}, "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}

{
                    "email" => "",
                 "password" => "",
    "password_confirmation" => ""
}
```

Am I missing something here?

### Workaround

A workaround would be to:

```
def other_signup_params
    params.require(:extra_user_attributes).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

Which works just fine, but it just doesn't feel right. I feel like I ***should*** be able to use the built in `configure_sign_up_parameters` method that Devise provides but I'm somehow doing something wrong. Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with devise, but a problem with the nested parameters I set up.

```
<%= fields_for(:extra_user_attributes) do |pa| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= pa.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= pa.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= pa.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= pa.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The `fields_for` did not get associated with the parent form, and got orphaned. It should have read:

`<%= f.fields_for(:extra_user_attributes) do |pa| %>`

Then, the sanitizer properly permits the fields:

```
{
                    "email" => "foo@example.com",
                 "password" => "hello!",
    "password_confirmation" => "world!",
    "extra_user_attributes" => {
        "first_name" => "Foo",
         "last_name" => "Bar"
    }
}
```